# Difference between bash function declared with parens or not

Tags: bash, shell

Is there any behavioral difference beween a bash function declared like this:

```
function ql_release_lock () {}
```

and a bash function declared without the parens:

```
function ql_release_lock {}
```

by behavioral difference, I guess I mean any difference at all that we should be aware about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference whatsoever after the command-line has been parsed. The resulting functions are identical.

The only portable syntax for defining a shell function omits the `function` keyword, which is a bashism:

```
q1_release_lock() { … }
```

---

Note: technically, the syntax for a function definition is:

```
fname "(" ")" compound-command
```

or

```
fname "(" ")" compound-command redirection-list
```

A compound-command can be a grouping, using either `{ … }` or `( … )`, or it can be a `for`, `while`, `case`, `if`, `case` or `select` statement. I doubt whether taking advantage of this fact is a good idea, with the possible exception of `fname () ( body )`, which indicates that the body of the function should be run in a subshell.

In any case, you can observe that bash uses `fname () { … }` as the canonical syntax, by dumping the function definition with  `declare -fp fname`.

Comment: got it...so to create the most portable bash functions, omit `function` and use parens?

Comment: Correct; only that variant is POSIX-compliant. See also http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: So if there are bashisms in the functions, it might be better to use the function keyword, to ensure fast failure, maybe?

Comment: @userunknown, ...if you want fast failure, wouldn't it make more sense to do that explicitly? My usual idiom is `case $BASH_VERSION in ...` up-front; that way we can provide an explicit error message for either the incorrect-shell case or the older-version case.

Comment: @userunknown, ...there are also ancient ksh releases where `function` is allowed but changes how code inside the function behaves (making variables local by default). Using such syntax can thus result in not just outright failure but more generally undefined behavior.